# Convert string which is ISO8601 time to datetime2 in Azure Data Factory

Tags: regex, azure-data-factory

I have the following timestamp - 2022-06-15T03:57:32.0449668+00:00 stored as a string in cosmosdb.

I want to use ADF to convert this field to a datetime2 when migrating data from cosmosdb to azuresql using ADF.

However, it is not being parsed as a datetime properly.

It seems like using a derived column is the best way to convert my string to datetime2 but I cannot find any experssion to do so.

I want the output to look something like this - 2024-01-08T00:00:42.0000000 from a format perspective

Any help would be greatly appreicated.

Comment: Have you googled **_ISO8601 time to datetime2 in Azure Data Factory_** ? Because regex doesn't come with time format constructs.

Answer (score 0):

> I want the output to look something like this - 2024-01-08T00:00:42.0000000 from a format perspective

This format might not be possible in ADF Dataflow.

I tried to achieve your format with your input data by various methods but all those gave null values only. So, the below format only might be possible in ADF Dataflow as per your input.

```
toTimestamp(concat(toString(toDate(mydate,'yyyy-MM-dd')),' ',split(split(mydate,'T')[2],'.')[1]),'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
```

[image]